# Exporting Data from Postgres with Copy command in SpringBoot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to do an export of a PostgreSQL table from Spring-boot application. I've a logic to select all the records and map it to a CSV. The application presently retrieves all the data and uses CSV libraries to format/export it. There is also direct command from PostgreSQL to export the data (COPY command), without using any APIs. Is it a way to have this done from application.

Added Queries from Spring-boot and tried executing the copy operation, where the spring is not allowing the command execution.

CopyManager from Postgres is recommended with Spring-boot?

Is there a way i can get the data directly from DB without the data getting retrieved by the application?

Comment: *"without the data getting retrieved by the application?"* Then where would the data go, and how would it get there?

Comment: Meaning the data export can be delegated to DB (someway)? Application just takes the exported CSV from the absolute path in file system and pass it on to the web client (In the deployments the application and the database runs on the same server.)

Answer (score 0):

[`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) will create a file on the *database server*, so unless that's really what you want, don't use `COPY`.

If you want the data in a file on the *application machine*, use a `SELECT` statement, and format the output as CSV in the Java code, preferably using a CSV library.

Comment: Exactly this is what i'm doing now and Its working. Considering the data volume, the data export alternatives i'm looking at.

Comment: @akumaras You should have mentioned that in the question. Would have saved me from suggesting stuff you already know. --- What problem are you really trying to solve? Would be a good idea for you to **edit** the question and clarify it.

Comment: My bad, i gave a little info in my question about the present approach. Just edited the question